# Connection timed out error

Tags: networking, ethernet

Am trying to connect a device to my PC via ethernet. while attempting to connect its showing "connection timed out". why do this happen...i need to rule out this problem to carry forward my project.

am trying to connect via ethernet.

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean trying to connect using Point To Point Protocol over Ethernet (PPPoE)? Did you assign the IP addresses for both ends? In order to connect two devices, both sides have to speak the same language (protocol) and should be configured properly.

Comment: yes. i have assigned ip for both ends.but still its not connecting

Comment: You can check the arp table in your PC and see if the MAC address of your device is listed there or not. If you use Windows, then you can try open command prompt and run arp -a command). And also please make sure that both IP addresses being assigned are in the same subnet

Comment: i tried in command prompt..but fevice ip is not listed..is that the eroor ?? if so how should i add device to it??

Comment: I see. No it is not an error. What IP addresses and subnet do you use on both devices?

Comment: Ip of device is 192.168.2.10 and subnet 255.255.255.0 and system ip is 192.168.2.1

Comment: Alright. There is no issue with your IP configuration. The next thing you can do is checking the physical connection. You can try to replace the cable. Or you can use other laptop (if any), configure the appropriate IP and try to connect it to your PC. If you can ping from either side, then the problem might be at your device.